# imagerotate() function sometimes work and sometimes not

Tags: php, image, rotation

Sometimes **imagerotate()** PHP function doesn't work (no error, the image is simply not rotated), sometimes it works. It makes me crazy.

Here's my code:

```
if ($degrees == 90)
    $degrees = 270;
elseif ($degrees == 270)
    $degrees = 90;

// Chargement
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotation
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

imagejpeg($rotate, $filename, 95);

// Libération de la mémoire
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

In the htaccess I set:

```
ExpiresActive Off

#ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 hour"
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 hour"
#ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 hour"
```

so normally there is no cache.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the bug : the photo was in a popup which reloads the mother window. The problem was that the mother window has just uploaded the photo, so the rotated photo was overwritten by the original photo re-uploaded.